# UK visitor visa sponsor

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications, indonesian-citizens

I would like to sponsor someone to visit the UK on a UK visitor visa. However finding it all very confusing!

As a sponsor do I transfer the money to the person I am sponsoring? As I will be paying for the flights and everything while they are here.

I saved up money for many years to travel, met my boyfriend in Indonesia and would like for him to come and see the UK for a bit. I therefore gave up my rented apartment and my job and am now registered at my mum's address (she can write a letter to say he is invited to stay rent free). Does it matter that I do not have a job? I have over £10k in savings which will be more than enough for us both for his visit.

He however does not have any money, he has a job and can get a letter from his employer to say he will have it when he comes back, he also give the majority of his salary to his sister and family as many Indonesians do for her school fees, his family relys on this. Are these things enough to satisfy immigration he will storm to Indonesia?

May as well ask all my questions!...

Does his bank statements and letter from employer need to be translated? 
Also is it possible to travel abroad ie to Europe for a while and return to the UK (inside visa dates of course) or is it the case once you leave the UK the visa is used?

Finally does anyone have any experience with the flight bookings/reservations? My plan was to book a refundable flight in case the visa is denied or we want to change the date of the flight

I have timelines to call SITEL UK to pay for the call and get this information but the number won’t connect?

Any help would be appreciated thankyou

Comment: Why did you give up your rented apartment and your job?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you read this question [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) and this Guide https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/827480/Visit-guidance-v9.0ext.pdf which should answer many of your questions.

A few things to bear in mind:

- UKVI specifically advise against booking flights until the visa decision is known.
- Do not send the person you are inviting money beforehand. ECO’s typically tend to view this as ‘funds parking’ (see the question I linked to above for a full explanation of this term).
- the fact that you don’t have an income may count against you. Proportionality of intended spend to financial circumstances is important. Planning to spend a chunk of savings without a source of income may not be viewed as reasonable.
- UK visitor visas are usually multi-entry but the holder will still need a visa to visit countries where their citizenship does not qualify them for visa-free entry. Applying for a visitor visa for Schengen, for example, must be done from the applicant’s country of residence.
- Bank statements don’t need to be translated but all other documents must be in English or translated in accordance with the rules (see the Guide I linked to for more information).